# Powershell out-file and name the file

Tags: powershell

I want to automate our auditing process, where we provide the local admin members, currently this is done with screenshots. I cobbled together the below code, which prompts for a server name and create a file with the local admin members.  However this requires me to rename the file.
I want to be able to input the server name and have that also be the out-file name.  I'm just not seeing the tree through the forest an how I go about it.  Lots of stuff for appending file names but I didn't see anything for renaming a file you create.
Thanks

```
function get-localadmins {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param(
        [string]$computerName
    )
    $group = get-wmiobject win32_group -ComputerName $computerName -Filter "LocalAccount=True AND SID='S-1-5-32-544'"
    $query = "GroupComponent = `"Win32_Group.Domain='$($group.domain)'`,Name='$($group.name)'`""
    $list = Get-WmiObject win32_groupuser -ComputerName $computerName -Filter $query
    $list | % {$_.PartComponent} | % {$_.substring($_.lastindexof("Domain=") + 7).replace("`",Name=`"", "\")}
}

$Workstation = Read-Host "Computer Name"
get-localadmins $Workstation | Out-File c:\temp\ENTERSERVERNAME_LocalAdmin.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out

```
| Out-File -FilePath "C:\Temp\${Workstation}_LocalAdmin.txt" -Append
```

Comment: I've deleted mine; yours corrects an error that I didn't spot that I'd made.

Comment: Just a tip, you can utilize curly braces without the need to overcomplicate with string subexpressions to avoid merging variable-compatible characters @JeffZeitlin This also lets you specify scope still, e.g. `${script:Workstation}`

Comment: Yeah, that's something I keep on forgetting about. It wasn't the error I spotted after you posted yours, though; it was that I'd used the in-function `$ComputerName` when I was outside the function. Careless reading on my part.

Comment: Thank you TheIncorrigible1 that is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @jcarreiro Great!  Feel free to mark it as the answer